# Convert big number to chars - Python

Tags: python, string, int

I have an course in cryptography where i'm going to decrypt an RSA-chipher. Now when the decryption is done I want convert every number in the decrypted list (decryptList[]) to chars so the text is readable.

In decryptList[0] i have 138766332635707196740445712245626646062. How am i supposed to convert this number to readable text?

I have tried to go from string to int:

```
plainText = "stackoverflow".encode('hex')
plainInt = long(plainText,16)
print plainInt
=> 9147256685580292608768854486903
```

Now i want to go from plainInt to "stackoverflow".
Any tips how I should accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your example: use `hex` to go backwards from long to hex and `decode` to get string from hex:

```
>>> plain_hex = hex(plainInt)
>>> print plain_hex
0x737461636b6f766572666c6f77L
>>> str(plain_hex)[2:-1].decode('hex')
'stackoverflow'
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for python 2 and 3

```
import codecs
b = hex(plainInt).rstrip("L").lstrip("0x")
codecs.decode(b, 'hex').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you can do the inverse of what you did to convert the string to a number:

```
>>> plainHex = hex(plainInt)[2:-1]
>>> plainHex.decode('hex')
'stackoverflow'
```

In Python 3, ints have a "`to_bytes`" function that takes a byte length and a byte order (big or little endian):

```
>>> plainInt.to_bytes(13, byteorder='big')
b'stackoverflow'
```